# Approximate waiting time

Tags: java

My friend and me are making a multiplayer game for mobile devices .

We have trouble calculating the approximate waiting time for the games.

Every game needs 6 players to join. We know how many people are playing (1 game takes 2-3 minutes). We also know how many players are online and how many are looking for games already( < 6).

Can I calculate the time based on these info?

Comment: Approximate wait time for what? What would you need to be waiting for, and what is the criteria (what would need to happen) for which the game should stop waiting and proceed?

Comment: Presumably he means approximate wait time before 6 players joined and the game could start; that being said, you'd probably want to start collecting data on how many players will jump into another game directly after the first, how many games there are, etc. etc. and use those data points to come up with some estimate.  Super fuzzy stuff.

Comment: The time to gather 6 players will depend on the popularity of the game which is currently an unknown

Comment: In my opinion : no. You need more info

Comment: Yes, sure you can. There are well established algorithms for this (@see machine learning). How do you think stuff is *predicted*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this could be modeled with a multiple linear regression algorithm (a search for something like: *'linear regression java'* will give you some implementations).

In my opinion the function would take as arguments:

- time of the day
- number of online players ( here you could also consider only players that are not IDLE)

and output the average waiting time for one other player to join (you can multiply this with the number of players left to join).

A short explanation of how this works would be like this:

- *time of the day* and *number of online players* form a vector with 2 components. Lets call it `X`.
  `X = [timeOfDay, onlinePlayersCount]`
- you also have a value `Y` that is your average waiting time.
- now imagine that you plot the points formed from `X` and `Y`. You obtain a *cloud of points*.
- what you want is a line that will pass through your *cloud of points*. As you know, a line is described like `Y = aX + b` so you want to know `a` and `b`. This is where the *linear regression algorithm* comes into play and will give you those values.
- the `linear regression algorithm` will need you to pass it a set of `X` and `Y` pairs that you extracted from your system by yourself.
   Ex: at 12:00 AM when 200 players are online, it takes almost 38 seconds for a new player to join.
   So when you have this data you only give it to the algorithm and it will give you `a` and `b`.
- now that you know `a` and `b`, you can calculate `Y` (average waiting time) by solving the simple equation: `Y = aX + b`.

You can read more on these with a simple search. Also this is the way games like `League of Legends` do it as far as I know.

Note: there is a special Stack Exchange website just for machine learning.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for responding late i was realy busy. I could not test it with real data yet but i think it is what i need! Thanks again it was realy helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this by maintaining statistics on how often players have been signing on and asking to join recently, but that's going to be best approximation only. There's no way to guarantee that the 6th player will show up within a given amount of time, or ever.